# Solving this problem with Lagrange multipliers method

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Hi everyone I want to solve this problem with Lagrange multiplier method

This is the problem 
$$
   \operatorname{Min} F(x)=3a x_1+5a x_2
$$

subject to these Constraints :
$$
g_1 : (2.16/x_1)+(10/x_2)\leq 1
$$
$$
g_2 : x_1 \geq 11.25
$$
$$
g_3 : x_2 \geq  18.75
$$

> - (**Note 1**: I only know a little about **KKT conditions** for solving    nonlinear problems that has one inequality and one equality
>     constraints and i only seen that in an example , so i don't know much 
>     about method)
>
>   (**Note 2**: This problem is based on weight optimization of a symmetric truss (engineering design problem)  that i formulated that and **Objective function
>     F(x)** and Constraints came from    optimization problem
>     formulation method that uses finite element method    and reason i'm telling you this because
>     i think you want to know the origin of my    question)

Comment: What denotes $a$ here?

Comment: it's a constant that has a value that changes from one problem to another and it's not defined .....if it helps you can give it like 2 or 3 but i need an answer with those if it's possible

Comment: Can we assume that $a$ is positive?

Comment: yes definitely it's a positive constant because it's a design parameter

Comment: I get $$x_1=\frac{45}{4},x_2=\frac{75}{4}$$

Comment: thanks a lot but i wanna learn the procedure can you send me that ?
simply i wanna know what's the difference between KKT method that uses one inequality and  one equality constraints but in this problem we don't have any equality constraints and that is what i want to learn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $a$ is a positive constant we can ignore it and minimise
$$
F(x)=3 x_1+5 x_2
$$

Rewrite the inequalities with slack variables:

$$
\frac{2.16}{x_1}+\frac{10}{x_2}\leq 1 \implies \frac{2.16}{x_1}+\frac{10}{x_2}+s_1^2= 1\\
g_1=\frac{2.16}{x_1}+\frac{10}{x_2}+s_1^2-1
$$
Now the second one:
$$
x_1 \geq 11.25\implies x_1 = 11.25+s_2^2\\
g_2= x_1-11.25-s_2^2
$$
Finally, the third one:
$$
x_2 \geq  18.75 \implies x_2 = 18.75+s_3^2\\
g_3 = x_2 - 18.75-s_3^2
$$
Form the Lagrangian:

$$
\begin{split}
L(x_1,x_2,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,s_1,s_2,s_3)
 &= 3 x_1 + 5 x_2 \\
 &- \lambda_1
    \left(\frac{2.16}{x_1}+\frac{10}{x_2}+s_1^2-1\right) \\
 &- \lambda_2 \left(x_1-11.25-s_2^2\right) \\
 &- \lambda_3 \left(x_2 - 18.75-s_3^2\right)
\end{split}
$$
This implies the following partial derivatives:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1} &= 3+\frac{2.16\lambda_1}{x_1^2}-\lambda_2\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2} &= 5+{{10\lambda_1}\over{x_2^2}}-\lambda_3\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial s_1} &= -2s_1\lambda_1\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial s_2} &= 2s_2\lambda_2\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial s_2} &= 2s_3\lambda_3
\end{split}
$$